# ko.mapping.fromJS change object without recreating

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using *ko.mapping.fromJS* for updating my ViewModel after getting data from server. But the is a problem for me.

After ko.mapping.fromJS i get View with updated properties. But every time properties recreating with new data, not updating existing properties.

How to do so that I get updated properties of ViewModel instead recreating properties with new data?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [mapping plugin documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html),

```
Let’s say you have a JavaScript object that looks like this:

var data = {
    name: 'Scot',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alicw' }
    ]
}
You can map this to a view model without any problems:

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
Now, let’s say the data is updated to be without any typos:

var data = {
    name: 'Scott',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Alice' }
    ]
}
Two things have happened here: name was changed from Scot to Scott and children[0].name was changed from Alicw to the typo-free Alice. You can update viewModel based on this new data:

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

The last string shows how to update viewModel with the new data.